# Calling Objective C Instance Method from Another Class

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have class called "HelloWorld.m" and another class called "Person.m". I have declared Person instance in the HelloWorld.m class as follows:

```
Person *person;
```

Now, when the user touches the screen I fire the following method:

```
[person foo];
```

But I get the error saying invalid selector sent.

NOTE: Person class inherits from the CCSprite class. What am I doing wrong?

Person.h:

```
-(void) foo;
```

Person.m:

```
-(void) foo 
{
    NSLog(@"foo called!");
}
```

UPDATE 1: In the HelloWorld.h and HelloWorld.m I have declarated person as a property. Here is the call to the person.foo method.

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    [self.person foo]; 
}
```

HelloWorld.h:

```
// When you import this file, you import all the cocos2d classes
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Person.h" 

// Importing Chipmunk headers
#import "chipmunk.h"

// HelloWorld Layer
@interface HelloWorld : CCLayer
{
    cpSpace *space;
    Person *person; 

}

// returns a Scene that contains the HelloWorld as the only child
+(id) scene;
-(void) step: (ccTime) dt;
-(void) addNewSpriteX:(float)x y:(float)y;

@property (nonatomic,retain) Person *person;


@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you import the Person header into the top of the HelloWorld file?

```
#import "Person.h"
```

Did you initialise the person pointer?

```
person = [[Person alloc] init];
```

Does the Person class have a foo method?

Comment: Yes, I imported Person.h. I initialized the person inside the init method and yes Person does have a foo method.

Comment: Seems like it is related to CCSprite. Since it says [CCSprite foo] unrecognized selector sent to ...

Comment: Thanks. Could we see the @property definition for person?

Comment: @property is defined in the above code! Thanks! For some reason I think it looks for CCSprite (base class for Person) for the method foo instead of the Person class.

Comment: I'm going through the list of mistakes that I always do and I'm not seeing anything yet. I agree with it looks like the Person is coming across as a CCSprite but I can't see how.

Comment: I went ahead and remove the inheritance from CCSprite. Now I am using CCSprite as an instance inside the Person class and it is working fine. Maybe CCSprite behaves strange when inherited!

Comment: It's very strange. Your code looked good. Wish I knew why it behaved as it did. Still, good to hear that you got a working solution.